# What is the preferred way of mutating a big state array in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Right now, I do it this way:

```
class Foo extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {data: Array(1000).fill(Array(1000).fill(0))};
    }

    mutatingFunc = (row, col) {
        this.setState((prevState) => {
            let tempArr = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(prevState.data));
            //mutate it here
            tempArr[row][col] = 1;
            return {data: tempArr};
        })
    }
}
```

But with a two-dimensional array of this size, there is some noticeable lagging, since the whole array has to be copied. Is this the most efficient way?

Comment: why keeping so much data like this in one array? Mabe if you could split it into more than just one.

Answer (score 0):

There's a much easier and faster way to copy an array:

```
const newArray = [...oldArray];
```

So just:

```
const tempArr = [...prevState.data];
tempArr[row][col] = 1;
return {data: tempArr};
```

Note that this is only a shallow copy. If you want a deep copy, there are many examples of array cloning functions to choose from.

Comment: How do I know if I want a shallow copy or a deep copy?